# Is this passage grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, british-english, grammaticality-in-context

We are an Italian independent art group and we want to adopt one of Mr. George's books into a screenplay, And we want to make a film based on that. What should we do to get Mr. George's permission?

Comment: You want to _adapt_ it, not _adopt_ it!

Comment: Don't capitalise 'short film'.

Comment: Also, it's "grammatically".  "Grammarly" is the name of a website/app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grammar isn't wrong, but some words that shouldn't be are capitalized within sentences. I think the word "adapt" might fit better than "adopt". The first sentence is a little rambling with three independent clauses. I suggest some changes:
We are an Italian independent art group, and we want to adapt one of Mr. McDonagh's plays into a screenplay to make a short film. What should we do to get Mr. McDonagh's permission?

Comment: ... into a screenplay for a short film?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That works grammatically, but it leaves open the possibility that the screenplay is the endpoint.

Comment: it's a possibility, but I don't think it would be the majority interpretation.